# jQuery alternate clicks do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so this little bit of code either posts and then updates #arrival, or it removes it and replaces it with standard text. One click posts, one click resets. The problem I'm having, and cannot figure out, is that the code as is requires two clicks to do the initial posting, and then one click to remove and one click to post again ad infinitum. But it first requires two clicks to get to working.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#change").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {};
    $.each($('input[name^="u\\["]').serializeArray(), function() {
       var vv = this.name.replace(/u/, '' ).replace(/(\[[]\])$/,'');
       data[vv] = this.value;           
    });
    var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
    if (clicks) {
     // odd clicks
    $.ajax({
       type    : "POST",
       cache   : false,
       url     : "napad.php?n=<?=$_GET['n']?>&o=<?=$_GET['o']?>&arrival",
       data    : {'X': data},
      success: function(data) {
        $("#arrival").html(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
    // even clicks
        $('#arrival').contents().remove();
        $('#arrival').append('Arrival Time: Normal');
    }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
     });
});
```

Comment: meaning that one button need to click 2 times then it running process? that you want sir?

Comment: No, no, no. The code as written requires two clicks to run the post, and then one click to remove it and then one to post again. What I want is for it to not require the double click to initially work, rather it being click the button once to post initially, once to remove, once to post again, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saying you doesnt want it firing 2 times but you want it trigger the event one time clicking.

try to add this on you jquery function.

```
$("#change").unbind("click").click(function() {
 // Your code       
});
```

Let me know if it works. Thanks. :)